# Save individual selection of global environment to Rdata

Tags: r, save

When we want so save the global evironment to disk we use `save(list = ls(.GlobalEnv), file = "data.Rdata")`- okay.

When one specific object should be saved we use `save(data.1, file = "data.Rdata")` - bien.

But what is to do when from an environment `data.1, data.2, data.3` only `data.1` and `data.2` should be saved?

Neither `save(c(data.1, data.2), file = "data.Rdata")` nor `save(list = ls(data.1, data.2), file = "data.Rdata")` is working.

Comment: `save(data.1, data.2, file = "data.Rdata")` or `save(list=c("data.1", "data.2"), file = "data.Rdata")`. From [`?save`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) (and every other function that uses them), `...` (ellipses) are "0 or more" arguments. And for the second one, it literally says `list: A character vector containing the names ...`.

Comment: Yes you're so right, I've missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many ways ... perhaps not countless, 'cause we "can" count them, but ...

```
save(data.1, data.2, file = "data.Rdata")
```

This saves just two objects, named, within the rda file.

For the latter form, you were close when you gave the example of

```
save(list = ls(.GlobalEnv), file = "data.Rdata")
```

Note that `ls(.GlobalEnv)` returns a `character` vector, which is what the man page for `save` says it needs. That should trigger the realization that this vector can be derived from `ls()` or from anything else that creates a vector, including manually:

```
save(list=c("data.1", "data.2"), file = "data.Rdata")
```

This latter technique is very handy when saving variables programmatically, where you may choose to not hard-code variable names (or have a variable number of them).

When trying to figure this out, it might be informative to try the nested commands first before putting them within a `save`. For instance, `c(data.1, data.2)` just concatenates the data objects, which may be useful or not; regardless, though, `save` expects an object in the `...` to be a symbol or object ... but a derived object like within `c()` won't work.

Similarly, `ls(data.1)` should have given you a reply along the lines of `as.environment(pos): invalid 'pos' argument`, indicating that your expection of the `ls` function is a bit amyss.

Comment: It might be useful to know that `save` saves the object with its appropriate name. When trying `save(c(a,b), file="a.rda")`, think about what the name for that variable would be, since it would be neither `a` nor `b`. If given *named objects* such as in the first example above, it captures the names (with `substitute(list(...))`), and then internally grabs the objects to which the names refer. The [first 13 lines of the source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/base/R/load.R#L60-L71) of `save` are mostly readable.